# hide activity when return from intent camera or intent gallery onActivityResult android

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, gallery, onactivityresult

I have an dialog who call to "Take from camera" or "Take from gallery" for add a new photo, this code works good, my problem is when return or close the intent if take a photo o take image from gallery. My activity from I called the intent camera and gallery, It's hide for approx 3 second and show again. My data in screen not lost, and show the image good, I did all but not find the solution for that. Repeat, open the camera with intent for camera or gallery, take a photo and camera finish, when I saw, my activity is hiding, my app all is hiding, later it show. Same with gallery.

Here my code:

```
case 0:
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
          // Create the File where the photo should go
          File photoFile = createImageFile();

          // Continue only if the File was successfully created
          if (photoFile != null) {
              takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
              mUriPhoto = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
              startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, TAKE_CAMERA);
           }
     }
     break;
case 1:
     Intent takeGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
     takeGallery.setType("image/*");
     startActivityForResult(takeGallery, TAKE_GALLERY);
     break;
```

And here my onActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case TAKE_CAMERA:
                ...
                break;
            case TAKE_GALLERY:
                ...
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: Check on another device....! 
May be its a device performance bug....

Comment: @ArsalImam No, already I tried on another devices. In a moto g, my phone is a Samsung s3. I saw something today, this happens when I called other app, like whatsapp for shared a text, or camera or gallery, when I call other app. It's so rare.

Comment: This happens with Lollipop.